# Call to undefined method JXMLElement::data()

Tags: joomla

After migration from joomla 2.5 to Joomla! 3.8.8, I get **Call to undefined method JXMLElement::data()** on launch of the index.php page.

Articles, modules and users are correctly visible through Control Panel; extensions and plugin seem aligned to current version.

Can't find any help on this specific error message.

Any suggestion? Thank you

Comment: Sounds like some code, possibly an extension, isn't compatible with the new version. We can't really help without knowing more about your code and setup.

Comment: in jooma settings, enable debug, and set error reporting to maximum, so you get a better idea of where the error happens. In case you can't access your backend either, you can edit configuration.php file directly for this

Comment: If the page is loading otherwise, it's probably a plugin.  You can also try and disable any plugins you have added one at a time until you find the source.  This doesn't seem like a coding question, you may want to try [joomla.se] the stack exchange site for joomla.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because should be on the Joomla site.